# java static generic hashmap with static generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have got something like that:

```
private  static LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, ?> configFiles;
```

and static method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getConfigFile(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {

    return (T) configFiles.get(clazz);
}
```

but I have got init method:

```
configFiles = new LinkedHashMap<Class<T>, T>();
```

and its no compile:/

But if I do something like that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void intitConfigFiles() 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, ConfigurationFilesException
    {
        configFiles = new LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, T>();
    }
```

its working but i don't know how can i use method put:/

```
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(prop.getValue());

    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        configFiles.put( clazz,  u.unmarshal(inputStream));
```

and I have got error in Eclipse I don't know how to correct use put method?

Comment: please provide us with the error message you get.

Comment: do you have amy un-caught exceptions in this line u.unmarshal(inputStream)?

Comment: You might be interested in using Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html), which implements a type-safe wrapper for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configFiles` should be of type `LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, Object>`; otherwise, as you observed, you can't put anything into it. `Object` will allow you to put anything into it, as anything is an instance of `Object`, whereas `?` will not allow you to put anything except `null` into it, because it must be an instance of an unknown type.

You should then create it with `new LinkedHashMap<Class<?>, Object>`

Answer (score 3):

`Class<?>` is not the same type as `Class<T>` and, since it is used as a type parameter, it must be exactly the same type. Since the type of your static variable has `Class<?>`, you gain nothing by trying to assign anything more specific to it. Just use

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(prop.getValue));
```

and put that into the map. Generics can't do much for your case, anyway, since the type `T` is erased at runtime.